# How to use xxhash approach to hash a vector with length of 100 to an array with size 7*7?

Tags: hash, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.04788.pdf) for compressing a neural network. It has used the **xxhash** approach to convert a vector-like input to an array-like shape via the concept of hashing. I would like to know how can I do that in Python?

Comment: http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/#other-languages ?

Comment: @Cyan, Thanks you are right, but how? The conversion steps are important for me!